# observeValueForKeyPath not being called when returning to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, uiprogressview, viewwillappear

I am tracking a progress with a `UIProgressView` and I set an observer to the property I'm tracking.

I add the observer in the `viewWillAppear`, like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"progress" options:0 context:nil];
}
```

And when I remove the observer in the viewWillDisappear, like this:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"progress"];
}
```

And in the observeValueForKeyPath method I updated the progress view:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object   change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"progress"])
    {

        [self.progressView setProgress:self.progress animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Now when I leave this `viewController` and I return the `observeValueForKeyPath` is not being called and I don't get the `progressView` continuously updated.

**The behavior of the progressView according to the code above is shown in this video:**
https://youtu.be/PVRT_Jjtdh4

Comment: Your code seems to observe your viewController by itself, in which there is no need to use KVO. That's expected if you don't leave the view, your progress view will be updated. What confuses people is in which case you have to concern about your progressView when you leave it's owner, thus the viewController. On the other hand, if your progressView is an outer view of viewController, what needs to observe the viewController is the progressView itself.

Answer (score 0):

Key-value coding (KVC) is a mechanism for accessing an object’s properties indirectly. In your case "progress" is the property of `UIProgressView`. But you have registered observer for the `UIViewController` object which doesn't have 'progress' as property.

**Hence replace `self` with `self.progressView`**

`[self addObserver:self.progressView forKeyPath:@"progress" options:0 context:nil];`

into

`[self addObserver:self.progressView forKeyPath:@"progress" options:0 context:nil];`

Also, do the same for detaching observer :

`[self removeObserver:self.progressView forKeyPath:@"progress"];`

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is when I leave the view and I return, the observeValueForKeyPath is not called and the progress view is not updated. But everything goes well while I don't leave the view.

Answer (score 0):

Find updated answer with example. This will help you :

Here you have to register as an observer of the value at a key path relative to the receiver. Also you need to set option.

Use :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [[Receiver Instance] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"progress" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
context:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [[Receiver Instance] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"progress"];
}
```

Rest is as it is.
Here, [Receiver instance] is the instance of class where you value for defined object progress is changing.

Comment: They are actually there

Answer (score 0):

Better to remove observer only after class is deallocated. So intsead of placing in `viewWillDisappear:animated:` you can do the same below :

```
-(void) dealloc {
      [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"progress"]
      [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Some think this is too late but the fact is Apple does this, e.g. `MKMarkerAnnotationView` removes observers of the annotation's title and subtitle in its dealloc.